# cocos2d make object follow the touch/finger

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I make my first app with cocos2d, so I am very new here

my first problem:

I wont to make the object (boat) to follow my finger.

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    NSLog(@"location X: %f", location.x);
    NSLog(@"location Y: %f", location.y);


    if(startGameButtonIsPressed == YES) {
        [boat runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]];
    }
}
```

It do follow but it is not fluid. If I move my finger quickly, it stops, and follow only if I stop.

**The second Problem**

How to calculate the distance between 2 points.

```
CGPoint currentLocation = ccp(boat.position.x, boat.position.y);    
float distanceApart = ccpDistance(currentLocation, location);
```

The problem, currentLocation is not constant on each point it has every time other value.... why?

Maybe becouse I have a scrolling background??

Comment: You should avoid using NSLog during performance critical sections of code.

Comment: But this is not the problem, if I remove NSLog, it is stil not fluid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `[boat runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]];` multiple times per second, which causes multiple `CCMoveTo` actions to be running simultaneously. This is not how **cocos2d's Action tools** were designed to be used.

If you want the boat to follow touches at a slower speed defined by you, you cannot queue up multiple `CCMoveTo` actions in response to `ccTouchMoved:`.

Instead, push the `UITouch` objects (or `NSValue`s of the `CGPoint`s) onto an `NSMutableArray`.  Then define a callback function to keep your boat moving after each CCMoveTo completes.

Example Code:

```
//...defined elsewhere, e.g. your header file:
    #define kBoatMoveTag 123

    NSMutableArray *touchQueue; //treat the array like a queue.
                                //don't forget to alloc it before using.


-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    NSLog(@"location X: %f", location.x);
    NSLog(@"location Y: %f", location.y);

    [touchQueue insertObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:location] atIndex:0];
    [self continueBoatMovement];
}

-(void)continueBoatMovement {
    //if no queued point, or boat is already moving...
    if(touchQueue.count < 1 || [boat getActionByTag:kBoatMoveTag]) {
        return; //dont do anything 
    }

    NSValue valueOfPt = [touchQueue lastObject];
    [touchQueue removeLastObject];
    CGPoint newPt = [valueOfPt CGPointValue];
    float distance = ccpDistance(boat.position, newPt);
    float duration = distance / boatSpeed; //you must define boatSpeed somewhere

    CCMoveTo *move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:newPt];

    CCSequence *moveSeq = [CCSequence actionOne:move two:[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(continueBoatMovement)]];
    moveSeq.tag = kBoatMoveTag;
    [boat runAction:moveSeq];
}
```

Comment: yes, but actionWithDuration chnage the spead the boat moves. not only the reaction

Comment: @Fincha I don't understand what you're trying to say. Please re-word your comment?

Comment: If I use [boat runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]]; the movement spead is ok, but [boat runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.1 position:location]]; it is too fast and stil not fluid.

Comment: @Fincha Yes, I understand that. I was trying to tell you how to do that correctly in cocos2d.  Updated my answer with clearer explanation.

Comment: @Fincha added a couple edits to safely start and keep your boat moving.  Make sure you use the CCCallFunc approach to continue movement -- this will help keep the movement look smooth.

Comment: where do I call continueBoatMovement?

Comment: @Fincha I edited my answer to call it in `ccTouchesMoved`.  If you don't see the edit, you may need to reload the webpage.  You may need to tweak my example some to get it started correctly.

Comment: hm it does not realy works how it should, but I will try to handle this. I mean in this example you move only while moving finger and you track the finger points, but my idea was to move only to the last point

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    //Declare the lastTouchLocation as a CGPoint
    lastTouchLocation = location;
}

-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];    
    CGPoint moveBy = ccpSub(location, lastTouchLocation);
    //Vary the duarion to make the sprite move slower.
    [self runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:location]];
    lastTouchLocation = location;
}
```

In cocos 2d ver 2 the touch dispatcher is a part of the CCDirector and no more a singleton class. Hence call this for the delegate functions to work.

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
```