# Cocos2d (Javascript) make object follow the touch/finger

Tags: cocos2d-js

Hello I have problem with movement of the sprite.

If I move my finger quickly, it stops, and follow only if I stop.

**MY CODE:**

```
  moveHero: function (y) {
  var self = this;
  let realY = y - cc.winSize.height / 2
  var move = cc.moveTo(Math.abs(realY - self.node.y) / 300, cc.v2(-126, realY ))
  self.node.stopAllActions()
  self.node.runAction(move)
},

// LIFE-CYCLE CALLBACKS:

onLoad: function () {
  var self = this;      
    cc.eventManager.addListener({
        event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,

        onTouchBegan: function(touch, event) {
            let y = touch.getLocation().y
            self.moveHero(y)
            return true
        },
        onTouchMoved: function(touch, event) {
            let y = touch.getLocation().y
            self.moveHero(y)
            return true
        },
        onTouchEnded: function(touch, event) {
            // x = touch.getLocation().x
            // y = touch.getLocation().y

            return true
        }
    }, self.node);
  },
```

There is a similar topic but in cpp: [cocos2d make object follow the touch/finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726218/cocos2d-make-object-follow-the-touch-finger)

I need solution in javascript. Im new in Cosos2d so I will be happy for all answers. Thanks!!